# Differential equation $y' = \frac{x+2y+1}{2x+y-1} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How I should solve this differential equation? Where should I begin?

$$y' = \frac{x+2y+1}{2x+y-1} $$

Answer (score 2):

there are different ways of solving this. the routine method is to find  constant solutions $x=a, y = b$ so that you have $$a + 2b + 1 = 0, 2a + b - 1 = 0$$ and then make a change of variable $x = u + a, y = v + b$ to get a homogeneous differential equation $$\frac{dv}{du} = \frac{u + 2v}{2u + v}$$ now make a further subs $$m = \frac v u$$ to go from the variables $v, u$ to a separable equation in $m, u.$  can you complete this process?